# Ubuntu 11.10 server shutdown automatically and boot extemely slow

Tags: ubuntu

Thank for spending time on this question.
The condition is that I have two ubuntu servers and both of them work well before. However, the place at where the two servers locate met a power cut. After that, when I booted the server, it blocked after showing fsck check OK message. If I left it along, the server will be ready at some time(very long from I start to boot.) I have tried to boot it with liveUSB, and it boot fine. I checked /var/lob/dmesg, and here I found some strange things:

```
[    3.015691] EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    3.015694] EXT4-fs (sda1): write access will be enabled during recovery
[   33.118353] EXT4-fs (sda1): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[   33.118360] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 36700192
[   33.118377] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 36700176
[   33.118381] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 36700175
[   33.118385] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 36700170
[   33.118388] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 36700166
[   33.118392] EXT4-fs (sda1): 5 orphan inodes deleted
[   33.118393] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
[   33.787452] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

---

...

```
[ 4647.882906] EXT4-fs (sdb1): warning: checktime reached, running e2fsck is recommended
[ 4647.889082] EXT4-fs (sdb1): recovery complete
[ 4647.889293] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 4648.620292] init: vsftpd main process (775) terminated with status 1
[ 4648.620314] init: vsftpd main process ended, respawning
[ 4648.622450] init: vsftpd main process (780) terminated with status 1
[ 4648.622471] init: vsftpd main process ended, respawning
[ 4648.624464] init: vsftpd main process (783) terminated with status 1
[ 4648.624486] init: vsftpd main process ended, respawning
[ 4648.626433] init: vsftpd main process (786) terminated with status 1
[ 4648.626451] init: vsftpd main process ended, respawning
[ 4648.628401] init: vsftpd main process (789) terminated with status 1
[ 4648.628424] init: vsftpd main process ended, respawning
[ 4648.630424] init: vsftpd main process (792) terminated with status 1
[ 4648.630446] init: vsftpd main process ended, respawning
[ 4648.632379] init: vsftpd main process (795) terminated with status 1
[ 4648.632397] init: vsftpd main process ended, respawning
[ 4648.634255] init: vsftpd main process (798) terminated with status 1
[ 4648.634270] init: vsftpd main process ended, respawning
[ 4648.636195] init: vsftpd main process (801) terminated with status 1
[ 4648.636217] init: vsftpd main process ended, respawning
[ 4648.638105] init: vsftpd main process (804) terminated with status 1
[ 4648.638122] init: vsftpd main process ended, respawning
[ 4648.640010] init: vsftpd main process (807) terminated with status 1
[ 4648.640031] init: vsftpd respawning too fast, stopped
[ 4649.225502] type=1400 audit(1405929155.476:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=825 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4649.225741] type=1400 audit(1405929155.476:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=825 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4649.225890] type=1400 audit(1405929155.476:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=825 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4649.542914] type=1400 audit(1405929155.796:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver" pid=824 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4649.543141] type=1400 audit(1405929155.796:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver//restricted" pid=824 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4649.607714] type=1400 audit(1405929155.860:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=826 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4649.607874] type=1400 audit(1405929155.860:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=827 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4650.404697] init: failsafe main process (747) killed by TERM signal
[ 4650.454079] type=1400 audit(1405929156.708:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=909 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4650.464929] init: apport pre-start process (885) terminated with status 1
[ 4650.476329] init: apport post-stop process (910) terminated with status 1
```

It seems that it will take almost 8 hours to boot... I have not idea how it happen, and found no resource to solve it...
Any help is thankful.
(I am a newbie of StackOverflow. If there are anything wrong, please tell me!)

Comment: I don't think this was programming related so don't be surprised about minus votes.

Comment: @MikkoViitala, OK... I got it. Sounds like I was misunderstanding stack overflow. I thought this forum was used for computer and information science while it isn't. Anyway, thanks for telling me this!!

Comment: Besides that StackExchange is about Q&A where you ask advise to your (specific) problem. It's not a forum where discussion flows, freely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why no one answered my question and even gave me minus point without telling me why. Anyway I solved this problem my self.

For short, too many small files in a single directory in file system may crash the system. If you have the same problem, try to recall whether you write a program or script that build a lots of small files in a single directory (in my case over 17,000,000 files was created.) Try to delete it and restart your computer. For fast deletion, there is a website to follow http://www.pronego.com/helpdesk/knowledgebase.php?article=59 (too much file to delete will cause rm -rf extremely slow.)

Following is the detail of my case:

After a long try, I finally gave up, and start to backup system before I reinstall it. I used rsync command to backup entire system to another work station and another weird thing occurred. The rsync showed that there were more than 17,000,000 files to check in a single directory. I stopped the backup process and used `ls -ld [the mentioned directory]` to see how big was the directory. It show me that it is more than 500MB...... Things had not ended! I found three other directory of this kind in the directory of same user... After delete all those directories, I restarted this server and everything worked find.

Hope I have given some contribution to stack overflow which is the best website to talk about knowledge of computer and information technology.